# SQL server:Inserting data at the same time in different table columns

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to Insert data at the same time in different  table  columns without specifying the column.

if i have 5 input boxes which have to be inserted at the same time into a database.
the inputs are as follows

```
<input  type="number"  name="Num1"></input>
<input  type="number"  name="Num2"></input>
<input  type="number"  name="Num3"></input>
<input  type="number"  name="Num4"></input>
<input  type="number"  name="Num5"></input>
```

[image: Input Boxes]

if the the database base has 10 columns as follows
[image]

Say for example, 5 numbers are entered as inputs 1,4,6,8,10
How can i store those numbers in the database on the same row in their respective columns.

 
Keeping in mind that the database column names are 1,2..10
The resultant database will look like the image below.
[image: Updated data base]

Can some help me understand how to achieve this results?

Thanks i look forward to your responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can name the columns something like mycolumn1, mycolumn2, mycolumn3, etc.

Using PHP, you could then do:

```
$col1 = $_POST["col1"];
$col2 = $_POST["col2"];
$col3 = $POST["col3"];

myqli_query($conn, "INSERT into myTable (mycolumn1, mycolumn2, mycolumn3) VALUES ($col1, $col2, $col3)");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table columns named as col_1,col_2,col_3.....col_10 then try this method

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
$num1 = $_GET['num1'];
$num2 = $_GET['num2'];
$num3 = $_GET['num3'];
$num4 = $_GET['num4'];
$num5 = $_GET['num5'];
$qry1 = "INSERT INTO table_name(col_".$num1.",col_".$num2.",col_".$num3.",col_".$num4.",col_".$num5.") VALUES($num1,$num2,$num3,$num4,$num5)";
mysql_query($qry1);
}
```

Comment: What if you dont know what numbers will be entered in each box. For example, you could have the digit 4 entered in box Num1, 6 entered in box Num2, and so on.. How will i write a query that will take the input and determine what column on the table to place the data in. At this point i only know how to put Num1 inputted data  in column `1` in the database.

Comment: see I have specified each column as dynamically.So in my sql query is in the format of  table_name(col_.$num1). So if you text 1 in first text box it takes like table_name(col_1) else if give 2 as input of first text box it takes like table_name(col_2).. Understand?..

Comment: It works but i did not quite get the flow of how it works. Some more light on the issue will be greatly appreciated